# Windows sharing folders appears to user without access

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, network-share

I have some shared folders SharedA, SharedB and SharedC, over a resource called WIN-RGHXXXXXX. Also have some users: UserA, UserB, UserC. Each user has it's own access to it's own shared folder in the following order:

```
UserA -> SharedA
UserB -> SharedB
UserC -> SharedC
```

My issue is when one of those users access WIN-RGHXXXXXX they can see SharedA, SharedB and SharedC. The user cannot list the content on the folders aside his own, but I don't want that user to actually see the other ones.

Answer (score 1):

[Access-Based Enumeration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772681(v=ws.10).aspx) is what you're looking for. Enable this and you can mask all folders from users except those which they truly have explicitly been granted access to via group or user ACEs.

Comment: Thanks @EEAA, I thought I was having issues by sharing through the advance sharing feature. I tried enabling Access-Based Enumeration on each shared folder but I still have the same issue. Tomorrow I will edit my question so I can replicate my current folder structure and the users access.

Answer (score 0):

You could create hidden shares and then create mapped drives. Users will be able to access their shares by connecting to a mapped drive letter or mount point and if they do browse WIN-RGHXXXXXX they wont see any shares listed.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd767761.aspx

Access Based Enumeration (ABE) wont help you here, even if you enable ABE the shares will still be visible ABE works on the files and folders inside the shares not on the shares themselves:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772681(v=ws.10).aspx